# Showing Details In Grid Format By Clicking the buttons based upon the criteria

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, gridview

I have designed a Page containing Grid Box with details fetched from Database.
I have included an additional option of Sorting out according to Priority.

My problem is that, When Pages loads. It shows the details accoring to the sorting. I mean I gave the dropdown for sorting.

Here is the code:

```
SqlConnection dbconnect = new SqlConnection(source);
string prior = SortBy_Drop.SelectedValue;
DataTable grid = new DataTable();
try
{
    dbconnect.Open();
    string result = "SELECT Title, Description, Priority FROM todolist WHERE Priority ='" + @prior + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(result, dbconnect);
    adapt.Fill(grid);
    Show_Grid.DataSource = grid;
    Show_Grid.DataBind();
}
```

But when page loads, it should so all details. Only When I press the Sort button. It should Sort accordingly.

Comment: This is filter, not sorting.  So call a method without `where` condition on page load and call this method on button click.

Comment: use a different query in your page_load event. how do call the code above thru method i assume?

Comment: Thanks All. I Have cleared my Error. Now My Page is Working Fiine :_)